'What's it?' vs. 'What is it?' in terms of usage
What's the difference between 'What's it?' and 'What is it?' in usage?
When and where, how often, and so on.
There is, for instance, this passage:
Can we go to the beach and collect another one?
A clamshell that size could take months to find.
There's just not enough time.
CLOCK CHIMES
PTERODACTYL SCREECHES
Time!
-That's it!
-What's it?
-Jen, you stay here and try and find your earring.
I'll be back soon with another clamshell.
Time to go on a prehistoric adventure!
But Andy, how will you...

Hm, I think we need more info to be able to answer. There is no difference of meaning, and hopefully you know that, so you're asking about using one or the other in different situations. Maybe suggest a few situations to focus on.

@AndyBonner There is perhaps a difference in style, for instance.

This question is similar to: can ' what is' be shortened in 'what is it'?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, "What's it?" is NOT grammatical, unless someone is asking about the word it which is very unlikely. It must be followed by something: What's it about? is an example.

What's that? but not "What's it?"

What's it? seems to me to be a perfectly natural 'echoing' enquiring response to That's it!.

You guys are just confusing the issue. I explained how it works in English, so there's really nothing more to say here.

You edited the question to add That's it,  but the text never says. I must say I expended a lot of effort on this and am not getting too much in return. :)

@Lambie I am really grateful for your input!!!!!!!!! One million thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! )))))

In the example you've subsequently added to the question, which is basically something like this:

Sherlock Holmes:  Aha! That's it!
Dr. Watson: What's "it"?

the question asked by Dr. Watson is parroting what Holmes has said, in essence putting "it" inside quotation marks.
Holmes is exclaiming, using the idiom, "That's the answer!" and Watson wants him to explain "That", not "it".  Watson knows that "it" means "the answer" in that idiom, but he doesn't know what "that" refers to.  Watson asks "What is the answer?"  "What's 'it'?"

'That's it." may also mean 'That's all.' Can it be followed by 'What's it?' in this case? How does it affect the prosody?

As I explained in my answer which also includes a grammar explanation. There is no idiom here. That's it. is idiomatic but it is not an idiom.

@Lambie  I'm tired of quibbling with you. I've had it.

First, there is no difference in meaning between the two. In terms of usage, "What is it?" can stand alone, but "What's it?" cannot. Otherwise, the only difference is that "What's it?" is less formal than "What is it." That's the only difference. Examples:
What's it cannot stand by itself:

What is it?
What's it?

"What's it?" generally needs a qualifier and is a little less formal than "What is it?" But that's it. Just a little less formal. For example:

What's it like? vs. What is it like?
What's it about? vs. What is it about?
What's it doing there? vs. What is it doing there?


What do you mean by 'What's it cannot stand by itself'?

I'll offer a different answer: It's unlikely to be found on its own except when there's special emphasis on "it."

@AndyBonner Could you please provide a couple of examples?

@Wittyhaire It means it's not grammatical in English.

@Lambie But it is used in dialects or in children's speech?

No one goes around saying: What's it? Children's speech is an entirely different thing. What's it do? A machine. What's it say? A note or letter. And in those cases, it actually means does. What does it do? What does it say? Also, see the examples in the answer above.

@Lambie I am asking specifically about the usage of 'What's it?' as a sentence in its own right.

@Wittyhaire Be patient, I'm writing an answer

@Wittyhaire You simply don't say "What's it?" by itself.

@Wittyhaire It isn't a sentence in its own right UNLESS you mean: what does the pronoun it mean? "What's "it" in your previous sentence?"

@Lambie That's clear, thanks.

This is dialogue ('dialog') from Andy's Prehistoric Adventures, a Cbeebies (BBC pre-school age kid's show).

Person 1: It would be different, if you took the situation seriously. Really.
Person 2: What's it? When you say, it would be different?
Person 3: It was an fortuitous even, you know. It really was.
Person 4: What's it? What was a fortuitous event? The fact they fell in love or the fact their relationship didn't work out?
Except where questioning the referent of the pronoun it, what's it is not grammatical in English.
In that sense, the questioning of the pronoun it can be said as: What's it? or What is it?
Bear in mind, however, that What is it? has other uses and is grammatical on its own or in context.

What is it, John? What's the matter?
What is it that you don't like about that movie?


As Lambie explains, What’s it? is acceptable  in the example you cite only because the speaker is seeking clarification of the antecedent of the pronoun that. Compare to this question-and-answer exchange—Q:  Has she been to London? A: Has who been to London?  Here who is parallel to your what.  And if I closed this comment by saying, “I hope that’s clear,” you might respond, “You hope what’s clear?”

When asking "What is it?", we normally emphasise is rather than shortening it. As Lambie says, in the example now provided, the question parallels "That's it", so it is the emphasised word.

"What's it" is much rarer than the uncontracted "what is it." Even compared to "what's this" or "what's that," "what's it" is much less likely. Here's an ngram of all of them:

Why is this? Well, of the three words "What is it," the word that is usually emphasized in our meaning is "is": "What is it?" "It" is a very vague pronoun; we can use it only if the antecedent is already clearly established. "It" is also unhelpful when distinguishing between things. If I pointed to a display case full of insects and wanted to know the species of a particular one, "What is it" is a strange choice. "What is this" or "what is that" is a more useful way of showing what I'm talking about. And for this reason "what's this" and "what's that" are more common than "what's it": Words that are emphasized in a sentence are rarely contracted. For example, I might introduce myself "I'm Bob." But if you say "No you're not," I would remove the contraction when insisting "I am Bob!" So, in "what is it," we might have the chance to contract "what is" if we emphasize "it"—like, "which insect"—but "it" is a poor pronoun choice for this situation.
A more common place to encounter it is in longer phrases, like "What's it to you" or "What's it all about." These work because the emphasis has been shifted to the later words.
Of course, you wouldn't use "what's it" in any situation where no contractions are allowed. This is very limited, though, to serious academic or legal writing and so forth. There are almost no situations in which spoken language should avoid all contractions; the robotic character "Data" on Star Trek is supposed to seem non-human for being unable to use them. Shakespeare's Hamlet is a prince, and he's not too fancy to say "What's Hecuba to him, or he to Hecuba?"

The ngram is irrelevant because it does not refer to a standalone question 'What's it?'. I would suggest you type < "What's it?" site:subsaga.com   > (preserving the double quotation marks) in Google and see the results.

For instance, >>>
No, a sheep gives us wool, B1N.
'Calista Croak.'
Exercise.
-In what way?
-When bees come near,
you see people wave their arms around to get rid of them.
Perhaps, but it's not the right answer.
Are you sure, honey?
'Charles Cheese.'
-That's it!
-What's it?
The answer! Honey - she said "honey"!
Yes, the correct answer! One point to you, Charles Cheese.
Bees give us honey.

ngrams not help here.

@Wittyhaire There’s a great example where emphasis helps, this time emphasizing “what” instead of “is.”

@AndyBonner And the emphasis is on 'it' only in 'What's 'it'?' ?
